# I am facing HTTP Error 502.5 error while publishing Dotnet core 2.0 mvc application in IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am getting below error while publishing in IIS 10.

Asp.net Mvc Core 2.0 application.

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Hegic.TwoWheeler.Web.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.3'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'

  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
    aspnetcore-store-2.0.8.xml
```

ThankYou in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have latest .net core runtime installed on your hosting machine

[.NET Core runtimes](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all)

If issue persists edit project file and set the following:

---

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you it works for me. as we need to keep latest version of SDK.

Answer (score -1):

I've experienced 502 error last month, but I've found out that I need an updated `Dotnet SDK Runtime Installer` version 2.0.6 as of today.

You can find it [here (.NET Core Runtime 2.0.6 Download Page)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.0.6)

Comment: Have you tried to restart your machine after the installation?

Comment: That's all I did and I got it working. You should drop an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues @Ankit It's the official dotnet core repo